# Online - Set permissions to Document Library using Workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, online

I'm currently using SharePoint online solution.

I've a list named "Projects" with the column "Title" and a column "People" (it's a people picker with multiple values).

I've already enabled a workflow that creates a new document library each time a new item is added in "Project" list. Also, this workflow breaks permission inheritance using SharePoint web services.

After this step, I would set new permissions (collaboration) to the created document library. I've tried using this HTTP call:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/test/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[%Current Item:Title%]')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=[%Current Item:People%],roleDefId=1073741827)
```

`[%Current Item:People%]` is set to return a list of IDs separated with semicolon.

It is currently not working. I guess is not possible to use the list of IDs.

So, should I have to iterate over "People" values in a loop? Then retrieve principal id for each user and then make the call to set permissions?

Is there any example to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is not possible to use addroleassignment where principalid is a list of semicolon-delimited User IDs. Both principalid and roledefid are of type Int32. Also, manipulating [%Current Item:People%] to separate the User IDs into independent variables is a great solution. The following Stage will assist you in accomplishing this:

```
Stage:Set Item-Level Access
    Log Stage: Set Item Level-Access to the workflow history list

/*
  dictRequestHeaders Dictionary Items:
  Accept, String, application/json;odata=verbose
  Content-Type, String, application/json;odata=verbose
  Content-Length, String, 255
*/

  Build {...} Dictionary (Output to Variable: dictRequestHeaders )
  Set Variable: strAccessGroupIDs to Current Item:Access Groups

/*
  Perform a POST API call to break permission inheritance
*/

    App Step
        The actions of this step can read from and write to all items in this site.
            Call [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[%Workflow Context:List Name%]')/items([%Current Item:ID%])/BreakRoleInheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true) HTTP web service with request (ResponseContent to response |ResponseHeaders to responseHeaders |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: strBreakRoleInheritance )

/*
  The following Loop will:
  1 Separate User IDs from a semicolon-delimited string to individual strings
  2 Grant Read access to individual Users IDs
  3 Verify access was granted to each User ID
*/

  Set Variable: boolLoop to Yes
    Loop: Call AddRoleAssignment for Each User ID
        The contents of this loop will run repeatedly while: Variable: boolLoop equals Yes

/*
  Count characters from the beginning of strAccessGroupIDs to the first ";"
*/

            Find ; in Variable: strAccessGroupIDs (Output to Variable: intAccessGroupIDLength )

/*
  The following If will execute when there is one User ID in all User IDs
  The following Else will execute when there are many User IDs in all User IDs
*/

            If Variable: intAccessGroupIDLength is less than 0

/*
  Stop looping
  Set the User ID that will receive access
*/

                Set Variable: boolLoop to No
                Set Variable: strAccessGroupID to Variable: strAccessGroupIDs
            Else

/*
  Copy the first User ID from all User IDs
  Replace the first User ID with a " "
  Remove the space from the beginning of all User IDs
*/

                Copy Variable: intAccessGroupIDLength characters from start of Variable: strAccessGroupIDs (Output to Variable: strAccessGroupID )
                Replace [%Variable: strAccessGroupID%]; with   in Variable: strAccessGroupIDs (Output to Variable: strAccessGroupIDs )
                Trim Variable: strAccessGroupIDs (Output to Variable: strAccessGroupIDs )

/*
  Perform a POST API call to grant Read access to a User ID
*/

            App Step
                The actions of this step can read from and write to all items in this site.
                    Call [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[%Workflow Context:List Name%]')/items([%Current Item:ID%])/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=[%Variable: strAccessGroupID%],roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP web service with request (ResponseContent to response |ResponseHeaders to responseHeaders |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: strAddRoleAssignment​ )

/*
  Ensure the API call returned "OK"
*/

            Step: Validate (strAddRoleAssignment​​)
                Log Step: Validate (strAddRoleAssignment​​) to the workflow history list
                If Variable: strAddRoleAssignment​ not equals OK
                    Set Variable: boolLoop to No
                    Set Variable: strError to Step: Validate (strAddRoleAssignment​...
                Log /Step: Validate to the workflow history list
    Log /Stage: Set Item-Level Access to the workflow history list
Transition to stage
    If Variable: strError is empty value
        Go to End of Workflow
    Else
        Go to Error
```

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

> Users, groups, and roles REST API reference. (2015, January 08). Retrieved February 07, 2018, from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx